# Randomly reduce instances on Z axis

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances, axis, random

I am trying to randomly reduce instances placed on a grid in the Z-Axis.

[image]

This is an example for what I am looking for.
How can I achieve this using Geometry Nodes?
I'll attach my example file, which is pretty close to nothing.

https://we.tl/t-yQhdoDq4re

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This task could be solved with the node `Random Value`:

[image]

Since your grid is not regularly structured in terms of the indices, you cannot use the indices for an evaluation.

Therefore I would work with the Z-position.

If you set the node `Random Value` to the option *Boolean*, it will generate $0$ or $1$ depending on the value for *Probability* with a certain probability.

As value for this *Probability* you use in your case simply the values of the Z-positions of your grid, and map them to a range of your choice. In this case your grid has a size range of $-1$ and $1$ on the Z-axis, so I use exactly this values in the node `Map Range`. You could also create this on automatically using the bounding box.

Comment: Hi Quellenform, thank you for the answer :-)
Is it possible to use the extract the remaining empty points?
I created two collections. One for the lower objects and one for the higher objects.
They should not share the same point.
I copied the script and fliped the map range. I thought with the same seed it should use the empty points which was not the case.
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Schmidtli Yes, of course, that is also possible. For this you would simply use the previously created selection to separate the points from each other with `Separate Geometry` and process them differently. Something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHdfc.jpg

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much :-)